# SQL query - count the number of items sold

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve the following question:

How many items with ListPrice more than $1000 have been sold?

The query gives me the results per Product ID, but I would need the total number of item sold.

I can't figure out how to do that.

This is my query:

```
select count(pro.ProductID), pro.Name, pro.ListPrice
from Product as pro
    join  SalesOrderDetail as sod
        on (pro.ProductID = sod.ProductID)
where pro.ListPrice > 1000
group by pro.ProductID, pro.Name, pro.ListPrice
having count(*)
```

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using ?

Comment: is it just as simple as...
`select count(*)
from Product as pro
join SalesOrderDetail as sod on (pro.ProductID = sod.ProductID)
where pro.ListPrice > 1000`

i feel i am missing something but this should give you the total amount of items sold that have a list price over $1000

Comment: It will return the correct result if you simply remove the 2 last lines. You do not need to GROUP BY any field to get the count you want.

Comment: Thank you. I now have the correct result.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. in your case do `group by pro.Name, pro.ListPrice`.

Comment: BTW, that HAVING clause makes no sense, and is actually invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the details you provided, your query should be like below :

```
select count(pro.ProductID)
from Product as pro
    join  SalesOrderDetail as sod
        on pro.ProductID = sod.ProductID
where pro.ListPrice > 1000
```